# Converting Chinese UTF8 to readable string

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'm trying to convert Chinese characters in a XML file to readable Chinese string using javascript, but I'm not sure how to. I have checked other SO posts, and tried the following

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent('&#x4E18;'))
```

but still can't get it to work, and wondering if someone could help?

```
<utf8>&#x4E18;</utf8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `unescape` nor `encodeURIComponent` (which deal with [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) will help you with a [XML character entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). You just want to [*parse* the XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+xml+%5bjavascript%5d)! Accessing the DOM then will yield the expected string.

Comment: Oh wow, I just asked such a stupid question. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you!